# how to filter dataframe with removing NULL values from selected rows in python?

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'dept':['dept1','dept2','dept3','dept4','dept5'],
                 'room1':['0','1','1','NA','1'],
                 'room2':['1','0','NA','1','1'],
                 'room3':['0','0','1','NA','1'],
                 'room4':['1','NA','1','1','1'],
                 'count':['4','3','3','2','4']}


        dept  room1  room2 room3  room4 count
0      dept1    0      1     0      1    4
1      dept2    1      0     0      NA   3
2      dept3    1      NA    1      1    3
3      dept4    NA     1    NA      1    2
4      dept5    1      1    1       1    4
```

i have a selectbox where the user can filter the required data and display  records based on his selection.

expected result:

if user select **dept2** :

```
       dept  room1  room2 room3   
0      dept2    1      0     0
```

if user select **dept4**:

```
       dept    room2     room4
0      dept4     1         1
```

## code:

```
option_dept = df["dept"].unique().tolist()
selected_dept = st.multiselect("search by departement",option_dept)
if selected_dept:
  df= df[df["dept"].isin(selected_dept)]

st.write(df)
```

**the problem is that with this code all the columns are displayed**

how can i remove the columns that includes **NA** or null in each selected row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select only `dept` and `room` columns, replace possible strings `NA` to `NaN`s and remove missing columns:

```
df= df[df["dept"].isin(selected_dept)].filter(regex='room|dept').replace('NA', np.nan).dropna(axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df= df[df["dept"].isin(selected_dept)].drop('count', axis=1).replace('NA', np.nan).dropna(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the user selects `dept2` then this code would give you the desired output,

```
pd.DataFrame(df.loc[1, :].dropna()).T
```

Output -

|  | dept | room1 | room2 | room3 | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dept2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 |

For other `dept` values, just change the row number in the `iloc` function. You can even set the indices of the dataframe to the `dept` value for that row using `df.set_index("dept")` and then use `df.loc["dept_2", :]` to get the data for that row.